# Having trouble resizing a QLabel in a QScrollArea

Tags: qt, qt5

I'm trying to follow the example at the below link to have a picture (in a qlabel) shown in a scrollable area.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-imageviewer-example.html

I'm using Qt Designer to make the ui instead of hardcoding everything. So I have a QLabel, in a QWidget (with a grid layout assigned to it), in a QScrollArea.

From the tutorial, they state the following for the sizepolicy of the QLabel:

> We set imageLabel's [QLabel] size policy to ignored, making the users able to scale the image to whatever size they want when the Fit to Window option is turned on. Otherwise, the default size policy (preferred) will make scroll bars appear when the scroll area becomes smaller than the label's minimum size hint.

Setting it to ignored fits to the window, as expected and as stated. Setting it to preferred provides scroll bars when the image is larger than the scroll area, also as expected and as stated. My issue is that when the sizepolicy is set to preferred, the resize function of the QLabel doesn't work. It always stays at the default size of the loaded image. The only way that I'm able to get the resize function to work is when I don't assign a layout/break the layout to the widget in the QScrollArea, but then no scrollbars will appear when the image is larger than the QScrollArea.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to make the resize function and scrollbars work at the same time?

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm trying to learn qt5 still and this seems like it'd be a simple thing to do, but it's slowly driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any ideas of how to make the resize function and scrollbars work at the same time?

If by "resize function" you mean the resizing functionality overall, you could switch to `fixed` policy rather than `preferred` and then use `setFixedSize` method rather than the `resize` method. This will both resize the `QLabel` and have the scrollbars for its parent `QScrollArea` adapt to the new size automatically.